# sorting array by values A to AZ?

Tags: php

OK so I have a head scratcher here.

I have an array and it was all in a random order I have been able to use

```
array_multisort($sort['key2'], SORT_ASC, $sort['key3'],SORT_ASC,$myArray);
```

Which has order `key['2']` alphabetically which is great, but the problem I have is I need it to be order A,B,C,D all the way to AB, AC, AD through to AZ

Can any one give me an idea on how I would do this ??

```
25214,10,A,1
30124,5,A,1
15248,5,AB,10
15248,10,AB,10
52568,7,AB,10
33331,6,AC,4
36389,4,AC,5
11224,8,AZ,4
88958,4,AZ,10
25636,1,C,8
```

I need it to order it like this

```
25214,10,A,1
30124,5,A,1
25636,1,C,8 <--- this is the problem all singe letters need to go before the AB ect 
15248,5,AB,10
15248,10,AB,10
52568,7,AB,10
33331,6,AC,4
36389,4,AC,5
11224,8,AZ,4
88958,4,AZ,10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure your code to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) instead of array_multisort it's easy, because usort allows you to define the comparator routine, and we can then write a custom comparator that first of all test the length of the string, followed by a regular alpha sort. Like this:

```
<?php
$arr=array('A','AA','Z','AB','C','BC');

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (strlen($a)!=strlen($b)) {
        return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr,'cmp');
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => C [2] => Z [3] => AA [4] => AB [5] => BC )
```

EDIT

although the logic is longer, the same technique can be used to sort a multidimensional array, you just need an appropriate implementation of the comparator function:

```
<?
$arr = [
['A',1],
['AA',1],
['Z',10],
['AB',10],
['C',10],
['BC',5],
];

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    // step 1: first we compare the string column, if their lengths are
    // different the shorter element is "less than" the other, and 
    // comparison ends here
    if (strlen($a[0])!=strlen($b[0])) {
        return (strlen($a[0]) < strlen($b[0])) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // their lengths are equal, so sort alphabetically, unless column 2
    // is different, in which case we compare the numerical columns
    $stringsEqual = strcmp ($a[0],$b[0]);
    if ($stringsEqual == 0) {
        return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return $stringsEqual;
    }
}

usort($arr,'cmp');
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Z
            [1] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => AA
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => AB
            [1] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => BC
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```

Which can still be extended to other columns and/or exotic sorting needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have to use array_multisort as it has to be sorted by key 1 then key 2 together

Answer (score 0):

String comparison will work in this case. You can use `usort`;

```
$array = <Your Array>

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $a[2] < $b[2];
}

usort($array,'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have to use array_multisort as it has to be sorted by key 1 then key 2 together